# Solving an equation with the same variable twice

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This may be kind of obvious, but our finance lecturer just assumes we know how to do stuff like this and the slides give no explanation. Jumping from question to answer

How do I get $r$ from this?

$27.397= \displaystyle \frac{1- \displaystyle \frac{1}{(1+r)^{36}} }{r}$

---

Answer:

$r=1.558\%$

Comment: This is not an inequality. It's an equation. Confirm it because none of the solutions is 1.558%.

Comment: John, it looks like you have the inverse of the equation used to determine the monthly payment of a loan without the principal term.

$$p = A_0 \frac{r (1 + r)^n}{(1+r)^n - 1}$$

Which arises from solving the recurrence relation $A_{n+1} = (1+r)A_{n} - p$.

So I'm assuming you mean 
$$ x = \frac{1 - \frac{1}{(1+r)^n}}{r}$$

with $x = 27.397$ and $n = 36$

Comment: You won't find a solution algebraically.  You need numerics, but the equation is well-behaved.  Excel has a built in goal seek that will do this, as will Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Your finance lecturer is paid to teach you stuff. Why not ask her how she expects you to solve such equations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to find the root $r>0$ of
$$
f(r) = \bigg[1 - \frac{1}{{(1 + r)^{36} }}\bigg]\bigg/r - 27.397,
$$
that is the $r > 0$ for which $f(r)=0$.
Using [Wims Function Calculator](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/wims.cgi?session=R21C9FC8B7.5&%20lang=en&%20cmd=resume&%20module=tool/analysis/function.en), I get $r \approx 0.0155764414039$, which is what you want.